# Jobs with high risk of death

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, work

While earning halal money is compulsory to entertain family requirements. Does Islam allow jobs with high risk of death?

As for example: Fishing fatality rate is 116/100,000 and many more. BLS reported there were 4,547 workplace fatalities in 2010. The highest number of fatalities by industry. [(source)](http://www.safetynewsalert.com/top-10-jobs-with-high-death-rates/)

**How does Islam allows/forbids risk percentage of Death, while doing a Job?**

Any help would be appreciated.